# What is the convex hull of this function?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Find the convex hull of this function:

y(x) = $\frac{1}{1+x^2} $

[image]

I'm attempting to understand the idea of a convex hull and attempted one of these problems. I'm a little confused because isn't the convex hull of this function just the function itself since contains every point and all points joining said points?
Do I have the concept wrong and is there something more to it?

Comment: That function is not convex and so not a convex hull.  You need to start with the definition of the convex hull of a function

Comment: Okay, Ive been putting more thought into it and realized the function can't possibly be the convex hull, but I'm thinking would a line y = 1 be a convex hull? Thats the smallest possible answer which encompasses this function

Comment: Could you give the definition of the convex hull of a function?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The convex hull of a function is derived from the convex hull of the *[epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics))* of this function. More precise

> The *convex hull* (or convex envelope) of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as
> \begin{align*}
> g(x)=\inf\{t|(x,t)\in\mathrm{conv}\{\mathrm{epi}\ f\}\}
> \end{align*}

See for instance *[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382825)*. Can you continue?